# how to get the offset top in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

how to get the offset top for `tr` in angular when I click the child node `td` `openClick()`.
I tried with this code below, I am getting error Property 'offsetTop' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf

```
<tr [ngClass]="value == 1? 'active': ''" class="tr-row">
    <td>Credit Card</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td (click)="openClick(1)">
        20
        <div class="table-inner-row"></div>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr [ngClass]="value == 2? 'active': ''" class="tr-row">
    <td>Credit Card</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td (click)="openClick(2)">20
        <div class="table-inner-row"></div>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr [ngClass]="value == 3? 'active': ''" class="tr-row">
    <td>Credit Card</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td (click)="openClick(3)">20
        <div class="table-inner-row"></div>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

my click event is

```
openClick(value){
   this.value = value;
   var box = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
   console.log(box.offsetTop)
}
```

Comment: Try `var box = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];`

Comment: easiest would be to pass the event along and use the parent of event.target

Answer (score 0):

When you do `document.getElementsByClassName("active")`, it will return an Array. If there is only one element with the `active` class then you will get only one HTML element in the returned array.

Access it like: `var box  = <HTMLElement>document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];`

I have given a type to the accessed Element coz `document.getElementsByClassName('someClass')` will have a definition of giving a return as `HTMLCollectionOf<Element>`

See it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xnk6v